# How to set up VSCode's problem matcher with Linux-style gcc errors

Tags: visual-studio-code, mingw-w64

I'm using VSCode on Windows 7 with MSYS2 + `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc` + `base-devel` installed.

I've got `tasks.json` for my project running `make` command to build:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "build",
            "command": "make",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

The problem is GCC generates a error message in the following way:

```
src/src_file.cpp:773:59: error: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness
```

while the project path stored in `$workspaceFolder` variable is `D:\myproject`.

The real path to the file is `D:\myproject\tools\src\src_file.cpp`. I have no idea how to set up the problem matcher in this case. I suppose that Linux-style slashes affect the problem, but I'm not sure. I tried to set up `regexp` for the matcher, however I couldn't get it to work.

UPDATE:

Actually slashes and backslashes don't affect the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this problem matcher, use $gcc as base and define the file location

```
  "problemMatcher": {
    "base": "$gcc",
    "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceFolder}/tools"]
  }
```

**Edit**

Removed the `src` because it is already part of the error message. (Did not spot it)